# Robolectric 4 test fails at Robolectric.buildActivity().setup() with java.lang.NullPointerException: Bitmap config was null

Tags: android, junit, robolectric, androidx

JUnit tests that use Robolectric.buildActivity().setup() inconsistently fail under AndroidX and Robolectric 4.3. Often in a test suite, the first two tests like this fail but the others pass.

My company has been migrating to AndroidX and Robolectric 4.3, and in the process of getting our test suite to a stable state, a few of our tests have kept failing. @LooperMode(PAUSED) was added to fix the "Main looper has queued unexecuted runnables. This might be the cause of the test failure. You might need a shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() call" message, and it stopped every single test from failing, but some tests inconsistently still fail. I tried converting to [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) to replace Robolectric.buildActivity().setup(), but the error remains the same.

This is an example code section where the test will fail, right at initialization for Kotlin.

```
private val activityController: ActivityController<TestHomeActivity> =
        Robolectric.buildActivity(TestHomeActivity::class.java)
private val homeActivity = activityController.setup().get()
```

And from a Java test, where the code is in a setUp() method.

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        [...]

        mFragmentActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(TestHomeActivity.class).setup().get();

    }
```

Again, most of the time only the first two tests in a set will fail. All the other tests will successfully init or get through setUp()

Here is one error message I get:

```
java.lang.Exception: Main looper has queued unexecuted runnables. This might be the cause of the test failure. You might need a shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() call.

    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.checkStateAfterTestFailure(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:470)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:548)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

That is the top part of the error, but the key is here, I believe.
BitmapLruCache is used to handle image loading.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Bitmap config was null.
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowBitmap.getBytesPerPixel(ShadowBitmap.java:674)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowBitmap.getRowBytes(ShadowBitmap.java:410)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowBitmap.getAllocationByteCount(ShadowBitmap.java:446)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.getAllocationByteCount(Bitmap.java)
    at app.base.network.util.BitmapLruCache.putBitmap(BitmapLruCache.java:47)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.onGetImageSuccess(ImageLoader.java:304)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$2.onResponse(ImageLoader.java:271)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$2.onResponse(ImageLoader.java:268)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.deliverResponse(ImageRequest.java:257)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.deliverResponse(ImageRequest.java:34)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPausedLooper$IdlingRunnable.run(ShadowPausedLooper.java:308)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPausedLooper.executeOnLooper(ShadowPausedLooper.java:273)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPausedLooper.idle(ShadowPausedLooper.java:85)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPausedLooper.idleIfPaused(ShadowPausedLooper.java:155)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.visible(ActivityController.java:174)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:251)
    at app.model.viewmodels.ViewModelTestHelper.setUp(ViewModelTestHelper.java:51)
    at app.model.viewmodels.ViewModelUrlGeneratorTest.setUp(ViewModelUrlGeneratorTest.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a full solution that addresses why this is happening, but I have a workaround. Following the steps in [this Robolectric 2.2 issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/876), I created this class:

```
@Implements(Bitmap.class)
public class CustomBitmapShadow extends ShadowBitmap {
    public CustomBitmapShadow() {
        // can also be some other config value
        setConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
}
```

And added this header to the previously failing tests.

```
@Config(shadows = {CustomBitmapShadow.class})
```

This doesn't explain why I didn't have to do this for Robolectric 3, but it is a solution. I'm not entirely happy with it, so I'll see if anyone can fix the root of the problem.